# AngularJS : How to mock a FormController injected in scope?

Tags: forms, angularjs

I have some validation logic happening inside a controller and I'd like to unit test this logic.

The thing is I don't know how to mock the form controller that is automatically injected into the scope.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, you can try 2 approaches:

1. use the `$compile` service, and compile your template with appropriate `$scope` (don't forget co all `$scope.$apply()` after compiling). Grunt's html2js is a great tool to preprocess your templates and have them added to angular's $templateCache before test execution. See the project's homepage at https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-html2js
2. use the `$controller` service, and manually inject `FormController` to the `$scope`. But you would have to also inject all `NgModelControllers` that you would normally have in your template.

Answer (score 5):

How about this for mocking an AngularJS form and then testing the form $dirty and $valid state:

```
// example usage of html form element
<form data-ng-submit="update()" name="optionsForm" novalidate="novalidate">

// example usage html button element
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="!canSave()">Update Options</button>

// Controller check if form is valid
$scope.canSave = function () {
    return $scope.rideshareForm.$dirty && $scope.rideshareForm.$valid;
};

// Unit Test

// scope is injected in a beforeEach hook
it('$scope.canSave returns true if an options form is valid or false if non-valid', function() {

// mock angular form
scope.optionsForm = {};

// valid form
scope.optionsForm.$dirty = true;
scope.optionsForm.$valid = true;
expect(scope.canSave()).toBe(true);

// non-valid form
scope.rideshareForm.$dirty = true;
scope.rideshareForm.$valid = false;
expect(scope.canSave()).toBe(false);

});
```